# How to get first vowel in a String swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, character

I want the find the first vowel in a string (apellidoPat) for example if my string it's "CRUZ" my expexted output is : "U"  what can I use ? a loop ??

```
var apellido_paterno = "CRUZ"
let vowels = "AEIOU"
    for index in stride(from: 0, to: apellido_paterno.count , by: 1){
            if vowels.index(of: ){
                
            }
      }
```

Comment: Do you consider "letter with diacritics" (like áèïōû) as vowels? How about ligatures (œ, æ)?

Comment: @Sweeper No only AEIOU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Collection`'s method `first(where:)` and check if `vowels.contains` that `Character`:

```
let apellidoPaterno = "CRUZ"
let vowels = "AEIOU"
if let firstVowel = apellidoPaterno.first(where: vowels.contains) {
    print(firstVowel)  // "U\n"
}
```

If you would like to do a case and diacritic insensitive search you can use String method `localizedStandardContains`:

```
if let firstVowel = apellidoPaterno.first(where: { vowels.localizedStandardContains(String($0)) }) {
    print(firstVowel)  // "U\n"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rangeOfCharacter` with `CharacterSet` to find first vowel

```
func getFirstVowel(name: String) -> Character? {

    let vowels = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiou")

    if let index = name.lowercased().rangeOfCharacter(from: vowels)?.lowerBound {
        return name[index]
    }

    return nil
}

print(getFirstVowel(name: "MIchael")) // "I\n"
```